# How can I roll a matrix in Tensorflow but set a different roll value for each index?

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix

Suppose I have the following matrix in tensorflow:

```
[[0, 1, 2],
 [3, 4, 5],
 [6, 7, 8]]
```

I would like to roll the matrix by `[0, 1, 2]` along axis 1, meaning the result matrix should be:

```
[[0, 1, 2],   # row 0 rolled by 0 - unchanged 
 [5, 3, 4],   # row 1 rolled by 1
 [7, 8, 6]]   # row 2 rolled by 2
```

Is this possible in tensorflow? How to best achieve it?

I have attempted to do this with tf.roll, but tf.roll does not allow varying roll amounts for different indices, forcing the entire matrix to roll by the same amount.

Comment: Naive approach: `tf.vectorized_map(lambda arg: tf.roll(arg[0], shift=arg[1], axis=0), (x, tf.constant([0, 1, 2])))` where `x` is your matrix.

Comment: Yes you are correct that tf.roll doesn’t support varying roll amounts  for different rows. You can achieve this desired effect using a combination of tf.roll along with some indexing. One way to do this is to custom function using Tensor flow operations. And another way To achieve the desired result of rolling each row of a matrix by a different amount along axis 1 in TensorFlow, you can use a combination of tf.map_fn and tf.roll.